# BYCOL formula to calculate difference of values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

in my example there is a yellow row (2nd row) with manually values and I want a BYCOL formula in row 1 (A1 cell) that retrieves the actual value of the column minus the value of the previous column. What could I do?

Here it is the example with the actual state and the desired result

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BX_XlNntT0CimtMGQmpRPA5OXbaesBPk7boPfPgp9A0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula instead

```js
={A2,bycol(B2:G2,lambda(col,arrayformula(col-offset(col,0,-1,rows(col)))))}
```

Seeing that you asked for `bycol` specifically, you can extend the above to multiple rows as follows

```js
={A2:A3,bycol(B2:G3,lambda(col,arrayformula(col-offset(col,0,-1,rows(col)))))}
```

Otherwise, for a single row, you don't need array function or `byrow` in particular. For a single subtraction, `arrayformula` with `minus` is more efficient and simple to code.

In any case, you can also extend the above to infinite ranges as follows. Assuming all rows end concurrently and no empty columns,

```js
=let(input,     A2:3,
     input_nb,  filter(input,index(input,1)<>""),
     numRow,    rows(input),
     numCol,    columns(input_nb)-1,
     minuend,   choosecols(input_nb,sequence(1,numCol,2)),
     subtrahend,array_constrain(input_nb,numRow,numCol),
     hstack(choosecols(input,1),
            makearray(numRow,numCol,
               lambda(i,j,
                      index(minuend,i,j)-index(subtrahend,i,j)))))
```

So at the end of the day, `bycol` is not the best for what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

`BYCOL` is not the right function for this problem. Try this out instead:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA({A2\B2:G2-A2:F2})
```

[image]

If you want to provide a single row input, you could use:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(row;A2:G2;TOROW(row-{""\row};2)))
```

[image]